Stripe Checkout - add second product with discount
We are using stripe checkout to sell services. We would like customers to be able to purchase another service in addition to existing and get discount for the bundle. Customer may buy second service later, not at the same time with the first product. Ideally it must be the same subscription but with higher amount.
Is there any easy way to do that with stripe checkout approach?

You would only use Stripe Checkout to start the Subscription. To add on a second Product/Price at a later time you would need to update the Subscription directly using: https://docs.stripe.com/api/subscriptions/update

So, there is no low code solution, right? Just create own UI and the call API.

You could look into whether Customer Portal fits your use-case: https://docs.stripe.com/customer-management
